# WCF service to be accessible by clients outside my domain

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm fairly new to deploying WCF web services . I hosted a WCF service in IIS6  and I want this
web service to be accessible by clients outside my domain

Please help me...
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Have you enable anonymous access for the website in IIS?
Do you use any other binding than basicHttpBinding?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that very easily. You will need to choose right `binding` like `basicHttpBinding`, `wsHttpBinding` etc.

Map your server to some DNS or IP. Open 80 port on your server, so that outside world can access it.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be referring to "cross domain" issues that I've hit when using Silveright. If so then "cross domain" gives you google words that will help you. More info ...

You need to add a cross domain service at the service's root. Now this is all very vague, as it is a bit complex and depends on your application, but you will need a config something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">

<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>

</cross-domain-policy>
```

If having trouble, the above provides a rich set of google keyworks if nothing else.

I have a service that hosts several WCF services. At its root it exposes the above cross domain service using this config:

```
    [ServiceContract]
public interface ICrossDomainService
{
    [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/clientaccesspolicy.xml")]
    Stream GetClientAccessPolicy();

    [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/crossdomain.xml")]
    Stream GetCrossDomainPolicy();
}
```

I hope this helps